# how to make submit button to point to view

Tags: python, django

I want my submit button in the template that uses a django form to take to another view or to just show the message that i returned in httpresponse. here is my code :

## views.py

```
def customer_form(request):
    form = customerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            customer = form.save(commit=True)
            customer.save()
        except DatabaseError as e:
            message = 'Database Error: ' + str(e.message)
        return render(request, 'bill.html')
    return HttpResponse("user added successfully!!")
else:
    form = customerForm()
    return render(request, 'add_customer.html', {'form': customerForm})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models 
class customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    purchase_order = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key = True)
    no_of_items = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    rate_of_pure = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Choice(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(customer)
    carat = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
    labour_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from models import *

class customerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

and template is:

```
enter code here
<html>
<head><title>Add Customer </title></head>
<body>
<form id="customer_form" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Choice #1</legend>
Carat:<br>
<input type="text" name="carat">
<br>
Item:<br>
<input type="text" name="item">
<br>
Weight: <br>
<input type="text" name="weight">
<br>
Labour Cost:<br>
<input type="text" name=labour_cost>
</fieldset>
</form>
<form >
<input type="submit" action="/start/" method = "post" value="submit">
</form>
```

in the last lines of templates, I have made a submit button, and i want it either to point it to a new view or sixth line of the view should be processed ie. after all the data is saved from this form, the message page should be shown that data is added successfully, how should i do that

Comment: What you need is redirect in customer_form instead of HttpResponse. look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: I got it.. thanks but my if part is not working ie even if i fill the form, the same form is returned showing that my form is not valid. Can u please check my code, I have done some editing.Also I want to know that how should I check that my data from form is being saved in database

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the response response, you can use a different template and render it

> return render(request, 'add_customer_result.html')

Comment: I did the same but i am still getting the same form after submission. Please help

Comment: edit your add_customer. html file. Add the following line`{% block result %}{% endblock result%}`. Then create a new add_customer_result.html file with the following contents `{% extends "add_customer.html" %}

{% block result %}
<p>User added</p>
{% endblock  %}`    . Now instead of returning a HttpResponse return render(request, 'add_customer_result.html')

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the way you have written views.py but [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-view) is the way I would have written.

Copying here for convenience:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

        # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```